# Parse Open push notification in different Activity Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

My Main is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Track app opens.
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    } }
```

and the my class Application is :

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

      public Application() {
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Initialize the Parse SDK.

        Parse.initialize(this, "KEY","KEY"); 
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class,R.drawable.favicon);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
      }
    }
```

When I click on the notification it opens MainActivity but does not return the result of the push why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Track app opens.
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        System.out.println("MESSAGGE " + extras.get("com.parse.Data"));
        System.out.println("Chanell " + extras.get("com.parse.Channel"));
        System.out.println("DATA " + extras.keySet());
        for (String k : extras.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("K " + k);

        }
    }
}}
```